# $("*") with exception?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A long time ago a friend made this for me:

```
$(".rnd1").click(function(){
    $("*").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });

    $('#random-button').hide();
    $('#recover-button').show();
});
```

now i would like to protect some elements (like body and #recover-button) from fading out.

Comment: in near future another friend will modify the code.

Comment: Why the heck would you like to do something like that? I wouldn't speak with a "friend" that wrote me a code with `$('*')`...

Comment: lol how about instead of iterating and applying something to everything there is! just put the things that will hide in a container and hide that? :) Can't believe people dignified this method by proposing suggestions on how to do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beneath the answers of the others, which are correct of course, don't forget that your "exceptional elements" should cover more in order to not make the whole document hideable.

So you will also need to make exceptions for `html` and the parent nodes of the elements, which you don't want to be hidden, too. Only this prevents the user from not being able to hide them.

Comment: this finally solved my problem. thank you all!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method to reduce the matched set of elements:

```
$("*").not("#recover-button, body").click(function (event) {

});
```

You could also use the `:not` selector, but as stated in the jQuery docs:

> The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable
>   selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not()
>   selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

On a side note, the use of the universal selector is usually frowned upon. Do you really want to select every single element in the DOM? It's not very efficient.

Comment: +1, But I would like to see a `*` warning

Comment: @gdoron - Agreed, that's a good point. I'll add one in :)

Comment: i like the side-note part more, universal selector kills the browser.

Comment: @undefined: Not if you use it as a delegate, as in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this and also deselect html element

```
$(".rnd1").click(function(){
    $("*:not('body'):not('#recover_button'):not(html)").click(function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      $(this).fadeOut();
    });
    $('#random-button').hide();
    $('#recover-button').show();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the universal selector problem, you can use [`$(...).on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate events:

```
$(body).on('click', "*:not(body, #recover_button)", function() {

})
```